# Which metrics are the (logical/physical) reads and writes in mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, io, nosql

I had a look at the collStats (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/collStats/) and serverStats documents of mongodb. These are pretty detailed metrics about wiredTiger. However I didn't found something that at least sounds for me like logical/physical reads and writes. Is there something I am missing? The closest metric I found are pages written from cache / pages read into cache and pages requested from cache?

Thank you!

Comment: I imagine you can test whether cache reads reflect physical i/o by creating a large collection, restarting the server and doing a find all on that collection. The # of pages * page size should roughly equal collection size on disk.

Comment: Aren't the attributes I mentioned pretty much the same? At least for my understanding they're describing the same: If I have a look at the values I would guess: "pages read into cache"  => physical reads, "pages written from cache" => physical writes  and "pages requested  from cache" => logical reads? Of course I would need to perform some insert/update operations to have a look at that values. I already did that but I didn't saw many "pages written from cache" at all...

Comment: Which is why I suggested testing with a large collection.